# Transition animation of QComboBox item's background

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

My goal is to create a slow transition animation of QComboBox items when hovering over them - I want it to slowly transition from gray color (`QColor(198, 198, 198)`) to white (`QColor(255, 255, 255)`) in span of over 300ms, this is how my code looks so far:

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
import sys

class ComboBoxDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if option.state & QStyle.State_MouseOver:   # if hover
            background_color = QColor(255, 255, 255)  
        else:                                       # leaving hover
            background_color = QColor(198, 198, 198)  
        painter.fillRect(option.rect, background_color)
        painter.drawText(option.rect, index.data())


class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()
        self.combo_box = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_box.addItems(['Item 1','Item 2', 'Item 3'])
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.combo_box)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        delegate = ComboBoxDelegate(self.combo_box)
        self.combo_box.setItemDelegate(delegate)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWidget()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

For now this lets me hover over items in QComboBox and change their background color however without smooth transition I desire.

I've tried using `.highlighted.connect()` and grabbing the item with it then tried to animate it via `QVariantAnimation` however it doesn't let me animate `QStandardItem` with it, then I've tried using `QStyledItemDelegate`, and now I am stuck figuring out how can I deploy this transition because I believe it won't be possible to take item from QComboBox as QObject.

Comment: While not completely impossible, this can't be achieved just with a simple delegate. The fact that you're using a QStandardItem is completely irrelevant, though, since nor the view or the delegate know (and should know) anything about the model type: QStandardItemModel is just a common QAbstractItemModel subclass, and therefore you should think in those terms. That said, the most important problems are that: 1. `highlighted` is only emitted when an item is hovered, but there is no direct way to know whenever it's *left*; 2. QVariantAnimation cannot be easily used with arbitrary targets.

Comment: Then, the issue is that you need to carefully update the animation along with a `editorEvent` override that should check the event type and eventually call updates not only on the currently hovered item, but also on *any* previously hovered item, in order to ensure proper repainting. As said, while not impossible, this is a bit difficult to achieve, and you should consider if doing it (and in a *reliable way*) is actually worth it.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried doing that today, however I wasn't able to figure it out